# Axios-запрос не работает. Почему?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Проблема - axios-запрос не цепляется к серверу. Ошибка "Network Error". Другие  запросы работают. В чем может быть проблема?

Гист данного запроса: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/97fe7fb3cdd1b11978274d99d8606a2c

Гист рабочего запроса: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3664a9d65e5918a9febb8b62dfcdc410

Answer (score 0):

Исправила - тип кнопки < button > на автомате является "submit", поэтому кнопка обновляла страницу и запрос не срабатывал. 
Нужно определить тип кнопки: < button type="button" onClick=... > ... < /button > .